# Screen readers & tab focus resets for vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Seems like focus resets and screen readers noticing route changes isn't part of vue-router.

I can see why vue might leave this out since use cases might vary, but I'm surprised at the lack of info about accessibility / SPA routers.

This seems like a common SPA issue and I'm curious if anyone has a recommended solutions to this or if there are plans to implement this into the core of vue-router.

Seems like dedicated aria-live region might be a decent option for announcing page changes, but I'm curious about resetting tab focus and screen-readers to the top of the new page once a user visits a new route.

Here's an article I did find.

https://medium.com/@robdel12/single-page-apps-routers-are-broken-255daa310cf

Comment: Relevant vue-router issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a library to address this: [Oaf Vue Router](https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-vue-router).

It takes care of:

- Reset scroll and focus after page navigation
- Set the page title after navigation
- Announce navigation to users of screen readers
- Hash fragment support

Installation:

```sh
# yarn
yarn add oaf-vue-router

# npm
npm install oaf-vue-router
```

Basic usage:

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import { wrapRouter } from "oaf-vue-router";

const router = new VueRouter({
  ...
  ...
  ...
});

wrapRouter(router);
```

Advanced usage: https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-vue-router#advanced-usage

Answer (score 0):

Here a short snippet for Vue 3 as composable. It resets the focus on the body tag on route change.

```js
/**
 * Reset the keyboard focus to the body tag on page changes.
 */
export const useRouterFocusReset = () => {
  onMounted(() => {
    const router = useRouter()
    router.afterEach((from, to) => {
      if(from.path !== to.path) {
        nextTick(() => {
          document.body.tabIndex = 0
          document.body.focus()
          document.body.tabIndex = -1
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```